# How to modify mvn.cmd to get the correct jdk build version in MANIFEST.MF file

Tags: java, xml, maven, pom.xml

I have installed 2 version of java on my machine, 1.7 and 1.8.
for building my java projects I'm using maven 3.5.0.

There are some cases when I have to build my java project using java 1.7, 
So I'm changing my `%JAVA_HOME%` environment variable to `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80"` from `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131"`.

Then I thought if I can make so, that pom.xml determine the version of java, by which the project should be build.

At first my pom.xml was looked like this

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <source>1.7</source>
            <target>1.7</target>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
...
</plugins>
```

as you can see there is `<source>` and `<target>` tags but this tags does not works for java 1.7,1.8, maybe it worked for earlier versions.

So I had to make some changes in Mavens "settings.xml" and in "pom.xml" files:

**settings.xml**

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>compiler</id>
          <properties>
            <JAVA_1_7_HOME>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\javac</JAVA_1_7_HOME>
            <JAVA_1_8_HOME>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javac</JAVA_1_8_HOME>
          </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>

<activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>compiler</activeProfile>
</activeProfiles>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <executable>${JAVA_1_7_HOME}</executable>
                <verbose>true</verbose>
                <fork>true</fork>               
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
...
</plugins>
```

Then Make build using `mvn install` and it worked!!! If I changed executable to ${JAVA_1_8_HOME} the size of generated jar file changes.

But there is one Big Issue in MANIFEST.MF. the build version of JDK is 1.8.0_161, so MANIFEST.MF will lie someone, who want to find out build jdk version.

The reason of this is that Maven (mvn.cmd file) looks to %JAVA_HOME% and takes the path of java. if there is no %JAVA_HOME% variable in environment, it takes the default system java -version which is in my case 1.8.0_161 (JRE version).

here is the `mvn.cmd` code snippet

```
@REM ==== START VALIDATION ====
if not "%JAVA_HOME%"=="" goto OkJHome
for %%i in (java.exe) do set "JAVACMD=%%~$PATH:i"
goto checkJCmd
```

---

**Now here is a challenge**

how to tell `mvn.cmd` that it was build by java 7 which is written in pom.xml?

how to make `mvn.cmd` to write the correct build jdk in MANIFEST.MF file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's solution, how to fix incorrect JDK version in MANIFEST.MF file . This fix will never let you to build your project incorrectly (if your configuration will correct).

At first it is necessary to remove Java link `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin` or `%java_home%\bin` from environment PATH.

Then you have to add new Profiles in maven settings.xml file

**settings.xml**

```
<profile>
  <id>buildByJava7</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>java</name>
      <value>7</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <properties>
    <java-version>1.7</java-version>
    <java-1.7>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\javac</java-1.7>
    <jdk>1.7.0_80</jdk>
    <wsimport>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin\wsimport.exe</wsimport>
  </properties>
</profile>

<profile>
  <id>buildByJava8</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>java</name>
      <value>8</value>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <properties>
     <java-version>1.8</java-version>
     <java-1.8>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\javac</java-1.8>
     <jdk>1.8.0_131</jdk>
     <wsimport>C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_131\bin\wsimport.exe</wsimport>
  </properties>
</profile>
```

As you can see there is global Properties `<java-version>, <java-1.8>, <jdk>, <wsimport>`. you can activate Profile using `mvn -Djava=7` or `mvn -Djava=8` command

Now you have to change Pom.xml in this way

**pom.xml**

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <verbose>true</verbose>
    <fork>true</fork>
    <source>${java-version}</source>  <!-- java compile version -->
    <target>${java-version}</target>  <!-- java compile version -->
    <executable>${java-1.8}</executable>  <!-- ..\bin\javac.exe file path -->
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

....

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <archive>
      <manifest>
        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
        <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
      </manifest>
      <manifestEntries>
        <Build-Jdk>${jdk}</Build-Jdk>  <!-- jdk version to set in manifest.mf file -->
      </manifestEntries>
    </archive>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

...

in case if you are using wsimport to generate classes from *wsdl, you have to add executable with wsimport.exe file path.
please foresee, that this will not work if you have java link in a `%PATH%`

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>wsimport</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <wsdlDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/app</wsdlDirectory>
        <packageName>ge.jibo.app.client</packageName>
        <sourceDestDir>${basedir}/target/generated-sources</sourceDestDir>
        <keep>true</keep>
        <bindingFiles>
          <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/app/binding.xml</bindingFile>
          <bindingFile>${basedir}/src/main/resources/wsdl/app/jaxb-binding.xml</bindingFile>
        </bindingFiles>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <executable>${wsimport}</executable>  <!-- ...\bin\wsimport.exe file path -->
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

After this modification you can just run command `mvn -Djava=8 clean package`

This command will activate `buildByJava8` profile.
pom.xml will get all java versions and java/wsimport paths from profile, and everything will be compiled and build successfully and correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I've just tried to use maven-archiver plugin to force a custom MANIFEST.MF and somehow determine the "Build-Jdk" entry. But it seems to always override the java version. If you'd like to have a try, check https://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifestFile.html

I don't think changing `maven.cmd` can make this script aware of the project peculiarities.

If the point is to avoid changing JAVA_HOME manually before some of your builds, maybe all you need is to make a wrapper batch file for maven 
referencing your jdk1.7:

```
SET "JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80"
mvn.cmd %*
```

Save this batch file as `mvn_j7.bat` inside your `[MAVEN_HOME]\bin` folder.Then you can run it anywhere, just like in the example below:

```
mvn_j7 clean package
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions